# what do you call a person who can focus on a thing perfectly for a particular period of time?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

[image]
Please help in finding the word.

Comment: Are you looking for a ***noun*** meaning *a person with a long attention span,* (most if not all candidates will probably be metaphoric / idiomatic / colloquial), or an ***adjective*** describing such a person (colloquial, or some domain-specific term that might be used by psychologists, for example)?

Comment: Up-voted, if you are, indeed, looking for a single word (noun) description. A 'focused' person, would describe them, but I am at a loss to think of a single noun.

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***single-mindedness***:

> the quality of being very determined and thinking only about achieving a particular thing:
>
> - *His quiet **single-mindedness** allowed him to accomplish something that others had been trying to do for years.*
> - *They demonstrated a remarkable **single-mindedness** in pursuing their goals.*
>
> <sub>[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/single-mindedness)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In the sense that light can be focused on something or used to narrow the field of view (spotlight). The word "**concentrate**" comes closest to the meaning you pose - verb (*to concentrate*), noun (*concentration*), adj/adv (*concentrated/ly*).

> You call them a person who can **concentrate** on a thing...

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/concentrate